# Grails on-premises

Tags: grails

We have developed an application using Grails, intended to be hosted on our public server and now we have some customers that would like to install it on their premises.

What would be a good way to license our application and limit it in time and in number of users?

Thanks, Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be looking for a standard Java solution to having the application expire. Something like: [https://truelicense.dev.java.net](https://truelicense.dev.java.net/) or http://www.websina.com/products/jlicense.html

Restricting users might have to be built into the application (in conjunction with a licensing libray). You could use a filter that checks the DB before each request (not very performant) or a Quartz job that checks peroidically and sets a flag which a filter could check and redirect to an error page if it's set.

cheers

Lee